User Session limit in Rockey Linux -8
I have a linux server running with Rocky Linux-8. When more than 5 users with same userid tries to connect to the server, the access is denied with error "Remote side unexpectedly close network connection". Following is found /var/log/secure
fatal: Access denied for user test-user by PAM account configuration [preauth]
Following the config in /etc/pam.d/system-auth:
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authselect is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    SECpamLogModule.so try_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      SECpamLogModule.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    SECpamLogModule.so try_first_pass use_authtok  sha512 shadow
#password    sufficient    pam_unix.so remember=5 sha512
password    required      pam_deny.so
#password    required      pam_pwhistory.so remember=5

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      SECpamLogModule.so

Config of /etc/security/limits.conf:
#

#*               soft    core            0
#*               hard    rss             10000
#@student        hard    nproc           20
#@faculty        soft    nproc           20
#@faculty        hard    nproc           50
#ftp             hard    nproc           0
#@student        -       maxlogins       4


# SH Update
# 4096 is a good starting point
*      soft   nofile    4096
*      hard   nofile    65536
*      soft   nproc     4096
*      hard   nproc     4096
*      soft   locks     4096
*      hard   locks     4096
*      soft   stack     10240
*      hard   stack     32768
*      soft   memlock   64
*      hard   memlock   64
*      hard   maxlogins 10


# Soft limit 32GB, hard 64GB
#*      soft   fsize     33554432
#*      hard   fsize     67108864

# Limits for root
root   soft   nofile    4096
root   hard   nofile    65536
root   soft   nproc     4096
root   hard   nproc     4096
root   soft   stack     10240
root   hard   stack     32768
#root   soft   fsize     33554432

I did change the limits in limits.conf and changed Maxsessions to 20 in sshd-config file but there is no change.

What is SECpamLogModule? I do not see it on my stock systems.

This is resolved after adding session limits in /etc/default/passwd fiele

This is resolved after adding session limits in /etc/default/passwd file
